# How to render a redux connected component in a modal

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, materialize

I am trying to add authentication to my react redux app, and I want to use modals for the login and signup pages. I have a `LoginForm` and a `SignupForm` which are static components, and I have `LoginPage` and `SignupPage`, which are my container components for the forms.

I am currently able to render the container components using login and signup routes, but I want switch to using modals.
Please how do I do this using a modal, say, `react-materialize` modal or normal `materialize css` modal?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting this answer, I would say you need to have two components able to communicate. This is the plain React way to do this. Notice there is one `App` component with two sibling components.  By passing a `props` value to the Modal component and a `props` callback to its sibling, we can get the modal to render or not render.

```js
class Modal extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return this.props.modalShow ? (
            <div className="modal">
                Modal loaded
            </div>
        ) : null;
    };
};

class Sibling extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.props.openModal();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                I am a sibling element.
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Show modal</button>
            </div>
        )
    };
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modalShow: false,
        };

        this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    };

    openModal() {
        this.setState({ modalShow: true });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Modal modalShow={this.state.modalShow} />
                <Sibling openModal={this.openModal}/>
            </div>
        )
    };
};


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

From here, using Redux is much simpler since the state is "global" already. But the idea is the same. Instead of having a parent control the state, just use your reducers and actions. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Chris, please any sample code on how to implement this? Sorry, but I am still new to this. Thanks

Comment: I've updated this answer with a better code example.